# TexStudio - Why is there no text on my pdf document?

Tags: graphics, pdf, texstudio

My problem is that I can compile my document, but when I open it, I can't see any text or figures, only equations. I have no idea where to start checking, the only message that I get is that the process was exited normally. In case you need to know it, I'm on a PC with Windows 7, 64 bits, and I'm using TexStudio.

Comment: Which distribution? Also, could you post a minimal (non-) working example?